# 2 Methods With 2 Different Intents... but Same Results

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to get some pusbuttons on the main screen to open new activities, unique to each button. When I click the Begin Test button, the TestSelection activity opens. However, when I click the Modify Station button, the same TestSelection activity opens, rather than the ModifySelection activity.

I'm totally new to this, so I'm sure it's a simple error. But I've struggled with it all day & can't seem to find any answers.

The MainActivity Java:

```
package com.example.android.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

//Called when user taps the Begin Test Button
public void selectTest(View view){
    Intent test_selection_screen = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestSelection.class);
    startActivity(test_selection_screen);
}

//Called when user taps the Modify Station Button
public void modifyTest(View v){
    Intent modify_station_screen = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ModifyStation.class);
    startActivity(modify_station_screen);
}
}
```

The relevant activity_main.xml code

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/modify_button"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/modify"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/test_text"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="modifyTest"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/test_button"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/status_text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/test"
    android:onClick="selectTest"
    />
```

I'm not sure if there's any other code that's relevant, but I'll include some more that may be

ModifyStation java

```
package com.example.android.test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import static com.example.android.test.R.id.test_selection_spinner;

public class ModifyStation extends AppCompatActivity {

private Spinner station_modify_selection_spinner;
private Button btnBeginModify;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_selection);
}

//add items into spinner dynamically
public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {

    station_modify_selection_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.station_modify_selection_spinner);
}


}
```

Test Selection java

```
package com.example.android.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestSelection extends AppCompatActivity {

private Spinner test_selection_spinner;
private Button btnBeginTest;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_selection);
}

//add items into spinner dynamically
public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {

    test_selection_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.test_selection_spinner);

}


}
```

Comment: replace setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_selection); in ModifyStation  with setContentView(R.layout.activity_modify_station); or use the layout file for ModifyStation  in its setContentView method, infact what you did is correct but you were using same layout for both activities

Answer (score 0):

in ModifyStation, replace

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_selection);
```

with its own layout file, now you are using TestSelection's layout file

Answer (score 0):

In your `ModifyStation` activity you are loading xml of TestSelection as:

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_selection);` Please change it to your xml of ModifyStation as: `setContentView(R.layout.modify_station);`.

This should work.

Thanks!